# API don't return CurrentUser. returning 500 internal server error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Startup.cs File Configuration

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            });
        });
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(list.Handler).Assembly);
        services.AddMvc(opt => {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
        .AddFluentValidation(cfg => cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<create>());
        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();
        var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
        identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
        identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();

        services.AddScoped<IJwtGenerator, JwtGenerator>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserAccessor, UserAccessor>();
        
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["TokenKey"]));
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(
            opt => {
                opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = key,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false 
                };
            }
        );
    }
```

My UserDefine Middleware

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> _logger;
    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex, _logger);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex, 
    ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        object errors = null;
        
        switch(ex)
        {
            case RestException re:
                logger.LogError(ex, "Rest Error");
                errors = re.Errors;
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)re.Code;
                break;
            case Exception e:
                logger.LogError(ex, "Server Error");
                errors = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Message) ? "Error" : e.Message;
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                break;
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        if(errors != null) 
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
                errors
            });

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
        }
    }
}
```

RestException File

```
public class RestException : Exception
{
    public RestException(HttpStatusCode code, object errors = null)
    {
        Code = code;
        Errors = errors;
    }

    public HttpStatusCode Code { get; }
    public object Errors { get; }
}
```

UserAccessor File

```
public class UserAccessor : IUserAccessor
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public UserAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetCurrentUsername()
    {
        var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault( x=> x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

        return username;
    }
}
```

this is my CurrentUser File that return CurrentUser Information to API

```
public class CurrentUser
{
    public class Query : IRequest<User> { }

    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Query, User>
    {
        private readonly IJwtGenerator _jwtGenerator;
        private readonly IUserAccessor _userAccessor;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        public Handler(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IJwtGenerator jwtGenerator, IUserAccessor userAccessor)
        {
            _userAccessor = userAccessor;
            _jwtGenerator = jwtGenerator;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task<User> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(_userAccessor.GetCurrentUsername());

            return new User
            {
                DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                Username = user.UserName,
                Token = _jwtGenerator.CreateToken(user),
                Image = null
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this through POSTMAN and the server returning And VsCode showing these error

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

`fail: API.MiddleWare.ErrorHandlingMiddleware[0] Server Error System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'userName') at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
at Application.Users.CurrentUser.Handler.Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
in C:\Users\NOYON\source\repos\reactivity\Application\Users\CurrentUser.cs:line 28
at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
at API.Controllers.UserController.CurrentUser() in C:\Users\NOYON\source\repos\reactivity\api\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 28
at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor
executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at API.MiddleWare.ErrorHandlingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\NOYON\source\repos\reactivity\api\Middleware\ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 25`

When I called user from a UserController then API say's

```
{"errors":"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'userName')"}
```

Why this GetCurrentUser() return username as null? isn't this a correct instruction to get current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetCurrentUsername() implementation correctly. After trying several time changes its working right as I want. Although It's now the same as I declared here. I don't know why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't post your `Startup.cs` file so I don't know what your current JWT configs. However, if you use `sub` property in JWT as username, you should add this line below

```
x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
     ...,
     NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier
};
```

If you want to get exactly one key in JWT token, you can get by following code

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwtTokenStr = httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", string.Empty, System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
var jwtToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(jwtTokenStr);
// Get Sub by this line
jwtToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Subject)?.Value
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I still get this same error. For provably you need startup file. I mentioned it above. Please Look at that once. If anything need let me know.

Comment: Did you try `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` instead of querying `Claims` ?

Comment: Also you need to ensure you add two lines `app.UseAuthentication();            app.UseAuthorization();` in you Configure method.

Comment: I Appreciate your solution but I can't figure out why this error comes from. I tried without claims query as you said and also apply authentication, authorization, But nothing happens. Can you suggest some topic as i might after learning them i could solve this.

Comment: I found it, seems you are missing to add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` in ConfigureService method, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I have been missed to add this services. but nothing changes if i added this services too. same error again